# How do the Injury and Death mechanics work (Flow Chart)

Tags: pathfinder-1e

**In detail how do the Injury and Death mechanics work?**

Comment: your question is not very understandable and doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: If you have an issue with the answer posted in your other question please ask for clarification over there. Otherwise there is no point in repeating what another question and answer already handles well enough that you marked it as accepted.

Comment: As per this it seems fine to me: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @winterblood I believe he is acting on the advice in the comments on the other question.

Comment: Yes, I have taken the advice from others and compiled this post as a complete answer

Comment: @doppelgreener I personally don't think it is warranted since this is already covered in another question, but that may just be me. Aside from that, @bennyboy please re-read the blog post you linked. You missed a very important point: `phrase it in the form of a question`.

Comment: Ok winter blood I changed How injury and Death mechanics work (Flow Chart) to How does injury and Death mechanics work (Flow Chart) :) The answers for the other post were not complete and I added new content to this one, it was much easier and clearer to do it this way.

Comment: I don't know Pathfinder. Is there anything in the answer that cannot be looked up trivially in the rulebook?

Comment: Hi, I don’t really understand the question. All of the data can be looked in the book in some section or another. It is not however in a cohesive whole or flow chart format, some sections in the book are vague and require checking different chapters for an single answer. In my opinion the death and injury system is rather convoluted as such its very difficult to have a clear mental model from the book alone, this in comparison is a compact single point of references.  I hope that answers what you are asking

Comment: If you want to discuss or challenge the validity of the reason a question was closed, please make that post on [meta.rpg.se]. If you wish to challenge the close process itself, [meta.se] is a good place for that. In either case, it might help to read the [help] on this subject and peruse previous meta discussions; this topic has been discussed before and it's good to come into it from a position of knowledge. **You will not get a question re-opened by turning it into a meta discussion on the main site.**

Comment: Thanks for the response BESW, I will go through the appropriate channels. Out of curiosity, is it wasting my time to do such as are the same people able to put a question on hold there to? effectively repeating the same process as here.

Comment: @bennyboy I've rolled back your post, since replying to folks is not what the question is for, even if it's protesting closure. I agree that bringing this to Meta is the best course of action, where we will have a little more room to discuss the matter.

Comment: If you do choose to make a meta post, try to avoid blame and instead focus on understanding *why* it happened and finding ways to move forward. If the close was made in error, asking for an explanation of the reasoning and how to fix your question to get it re-opened should expose the error. On the other hand if the close was reasonable and you approach this by calling Stack guidelines "silly," you'll get "It's not silly" instead of anything specific to your situation.

Comment: I have done my best to give a factual counter argument for my claim. Thanks BESW

Comment: @bennyboy, it's still best practice to leave the question as a question rather than a pointer to the meta discussion. Here is the link to the [related meta](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/request-for-reopening-a-post-on-the-following-grounds). I rolled it back to its last "question-like" state.

Comment: @bennyboy one of the (many) things you seem to misunderstand about this site is that moderation is a shared responsibility here.  There are literally more than a hundred people who can put this post on hold.  The same is true of any meta post you make.  Any of those hundred people can also reopen a post.  We have community elected moderators, but they *aren't* the moderators of the site in the typical sense-- instead every single site user is.  How much power they have depends on their rep.  And **you should really read the help center**.

Comment: The flaw is only a select few care enough to bother and those that do primarily band together. From an outsider view it just looks like those few members are just the standard mob to me. The same 8-10 people that voted this down, put it on hold and hang out primly in chat together. I guess a mob is what you are going to get when moderation in the traditional sense isn't used. So you have hundreds of people but that small mob of individuals act. I have gotten over the frustration anyway I have accepted this structure for what it is and I will move on to more productive things :)

Comment: Note that this post is being discussed on meta: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/request-for-reopening-a-post-on-the-following-grounds

Answer (score 2):

Far from a comprehensive guide I am sure, I have detailed the main bulk of death and injury mechanics as to my knowledge. In what I find to be a more understandable format.

Any additional information, correction or modification suggestions are more then encouraged.

I have completed this work with the help of [Xanders](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html#hit-points) and [Hey I Cans](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#difficultyClass) work

Please not as per this post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ it is perfectly acceptable to ask a question with the intent of answering yourself.

**WH**= with help, a character recovering with help recovers diffrently to a character without help.

**WOH**= A character without help, a character without help recovers differently than one with help.

**Constitution Check**= d20+ConstModifer

**HP**= [Hit Points](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html#hit-points)

**DC**= [Difficulty class](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#difficultyClass)

**Creature**= an active participant in the story or world. This includes **PCs, NPCs, and monsters**.

- If a characters intelligence score is 0 he/she is comatose(mentally and physically unresponsive) in other words [unconscious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious)

  - Refer to *2:*
- If a characters constitution score is 0 he/she is [dead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#dead-status)

  - Refer to *3:*
- If a characters dexterity score is 0 he/she becomes immobile(cannot move, not unconscious)

  - Refer to *2:*
- If a characters strength score is 0 he/she becomes [unconscious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious)

  - Refer to *2:*
- If 1 or more, the character is [conscious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conscious) and mobile.
- If 0, the character is [disabled](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#disabled).
- If -1 to -(the character's Constitution score -1), the character is [dying](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#dying).

  - [WH]If taking or not taking continues damage(like from [acid arrow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/acidArrow.html#acid-arrow) or [bleeding effect](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#bleed)) another character can attempt to stabilize the character with([DC 15 Heal check: First Aid](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/heal.html#first-aid))

    - Success means character becomes [stable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#stable) and bleeding affects stop. The character now only has the condition [unconscious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious).

      - Refer to *1:*
    - Failure means the character does not stabilize(*Trying again:* You can always retry a [first aid check](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/heal.html#first-aid), assuming the target is still alive).
  - [WH]If healed at least 1hp from healing affects(like the [heal spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/heal.html#heal) )

    - If healing brings the character to 0 hp he becomes conscious and [disabled](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#disabled)
    - If healing brings character to 1 hp or more the character becomes fully functional
    - If healing does not bring character above minus hp he becomes [stable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#stable), The       character now only has the condition [unconscious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious).

      - Refer to *1:*
    - Failure means nothing changes(Failing conditions may apply depending on healing affect).
  - [WOH]If not taking continues damage(like from [acid arrow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/acidArrow.html#acid-arrow) or [bleeding effect](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#bleed))

    - At the beginning of the character's turn the character makes a Constitution check(DC 10) with a penalty equal to the character's negative hp.

      - Failure means the character hasn't stabilized and loses 1 hp.
      - Success means the character has [stabilized](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#stable). The character now only has the condition [unconscious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious). At the beginning of each hour of [unconsciousness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#unconscious) the character makes Constitution check(DC 10) with a penalty equal to the characters negative hp

        - Failure means the character hasn't [stabilized](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#stable) and loses 1 hp.
        - Success means the character is conscious and mobile. After the character rests for 8 hours, the character makes a Constitution check (DC 10) with a penalty equal to the character’s negative hp.

          - Failure means the character loses 1 hp. This does not make him unconscious
          - Success means the character can recover hp naturally (i.e. 1 hp per level per 8 hours of rest or double that per day of rest).
  - [WOH]If taking continues damage (like from [acid arrow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/acidArrow.html#acid-arrow) or [bleeding effect](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#bleed))

    - At the beginning of the character's turn the character Constitution check (DC 10) automatically fails. Character loses 1 hp in addition to the continues damage.
- If negative the character's Constitution score or negative more than the characters's constitution score, the character is [dead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#dead-status), Refer to *3:*.

*1:* One hour after becoming [stable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#stable), must make a DC 10 constitution check to become [conscious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conscious), takes penalty on roll equal to negative hp.

- Failure means make another check in one hour to regain [consciousness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conscious) **only if hit points are zero or below**
- Success means player becomes [conscious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conscious) and is [disabled](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#disabled) until hp is at least 1 (through natural healing or spells)

Once the characters hp is at least 1 the character is fully functional and can chose to continue resting/healing in order to gain more hp.

*2:* When damaged in this way([Ability score Drain](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#ability-score-damage-penalty-and-drain)) and your ability score is 0(or negative more than 0) you may only "heal" the negative affect by increasing the ability score to a positive number.

> Unless otherwise noted, damage to your ability scores is healed at
>   the rate of 1 per day to each ability score that has been damaged.
>   Ability damage can be healed through the use of spells, such as lesser
>   restoration.

*3:* Once the creature has been killed, there is still hope you can attempt to [bring back the dead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html#bringing-back-the-dead) with spells like [Resurrection](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/resurrection.html#resurrection), [Raise Dead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/raiseDead.html#raise-dead).

Comment: What about wisdom and charisma (for completeness)

Comment: Yes indeed, that was in my draft I must not have copied it over. Will be added.

Comment: For anyone whom has an opinion on the holding of this post please refer to http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/request-for-reopening-a-post-on-the-following-grounds

Comment: Also points like "If 1 or more, the character is conscious and mobile." should make it clear this refers to HP

Comment: Why is this a CW?

Comment: Bullets 5,6,7, and 8 of the "main level" of bullets don't make any sense. If *what* is at those various values? (There are a bunch of other places where things don't parse, but I'm working from main->detailed.)